# Mongo/ mongoose don't return properties that are null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way in mongo or mongoose to leave out all properties that are null in a document when you query for that doc?

Ie if this doc was in mongo:

```
{
  name: 'test',
  other: null
}
```

Can I retrieve that doc without the other property?

If not maybe I can do the reverse and ensure null never gets stored for properties. Is there a way to prevent nulls from being stored w/o throwing errors.  IE there might be a way in mongoose to store specify a filed cannot be null but I do not want mongoose to throw an error if I do try to store a null, I would like it to be transparent.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Have u tried storing `undefined` instead of `null`?

Comment: No errors, I updated the question.  Just do not want to specify in mongoose that a field cannot be null and have mongoose throw an error if null.

Comment: @Yerken sure I can scrub everything coming into the server and change nulls to undefined, but I would like to see if I can get around doing that by have the database handle it.

Comment: you can do that in pre('save') hook